# Source for the Baal Shem Tov's signature

Tags: sources-mekorot, baal-shem-tov

According to [Chabadpedia](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91), the following comprises the signature of Rabbi Yisrael ben Eliezer, the Baal Shem Tov:

[image]

Is this *actually* the Baal Shem Tov's signature? Where was it copied from? The article does not say, and I am curious as to whether or not we know for certain that this is his.

Comment: he wrote a bunch of stuff, like letters.  Likely from those. (As an aside, see this nice exhibit on him here: http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/digitallibrary/gallery/jewish/Pages/besht-exhibition.aspx)

Comment: Note the signature is also on the normal [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baal_Shem_Tov).

Comment: To those who have voted to close, why? This question is not about Jewish individuals (although on face-value it might look so), but rather about the source, perhaps in a sefer or elsewhere, as to how they know this is the Baal Shem Tov's signature.

Comment: @ezra What does knowing whether a signature belongs to a particular Jew about Judaism?

Comment: אפילו שיחת חולין של תלמידי חכמים צריכה לימודא שנאמר ועליהו לתרופה

Comment: @rosends To those who are voting to close, does the edit help? I'm not just asking for a source now, but for verification that the Baal Shem Tov's signature looked like this.

Comment: @ShimonbM but, again, unless this casts doubt on his haskama to something, or the validity of a psak he authored, how does knowing what his signature looked like relate to Judaism, and not to him as an individual Jew?

Comment: From Chabadpedia:  "מצטער, איני יודע מה מקור החתימה. בברכה מפעיל מערכת".